# How to automatically move focus when selectedindex tab change in Tab control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `Tabcontrol` like this.

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}" Name="TabControlAll">
        <TabItem Header="Hal 1" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}">
            <kor:Halaman1 DataContext="{Binding RTDetail}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Hal 2" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}" >
            <kor:Halaman2 />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Hal 3" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}">
            <kor:Halaman3/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Hal 4" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}">
            <kor:Halaman4/>
        ...

</TabControl>
```

And the view can be like this.
[image: tabcontrol]

In my `UserControl` I have so many controls like Hal 12 with many `Textboxes` inside `Usercontrol` Halaman so what I wanna ask How I can automatically change keyboard focus on change `Tabcontrol` index to first `Textbox` in selected tab?

And I have to move also to next `TabControl` when focus of keyboard has reached the last control in that page.

Any body can help?

Comment: try `FocusManager.FocusElement={Binding ElementName=<TextBoxName>}`.

Comment: Am I have to set manually in each usercontrol?

Comment: If controls in your tabControl differ from one to another, then yes. If however your controls are using some base control, you would just set it in the base.

Answer (score 1):

This event handler will move the focus to the next TabItem when tab key is pressed.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Tab)
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = (tabControl.SelectedIndex + 1) % tabCount;
}
```

Upon moving the focus, you can set this event handler to last control in your tab item. This will focus the first control in the selected TabItem. You can replace *element* with the name of your first control.

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<UIElement>(x =>
    {
        x.Focus();
    }), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, element);
}
```

This should be working fine.